# How to open an image with default image viewer of device using WebIntents plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm building an application with phonegap and I want to create a function that enables users to click a thumbnail and the image will be downloaded and shown in a default picture viewer of the mobile device. Is that possible to use WebIntents plugin to do this?
According to the example `url: 'geo:0,0?q=' + address` opens a map application. What should I change in this line of code to make it open the image viewer showing a picture located in a remote server.
Thanks for any help.